# Jquery .load() and javascript .onload difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, jquery-load

What is the difference between these two, in term of functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200

Comment: possible duplicate of [js window.onload vs jquery $(document).ready()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/js-window-onload-vs-jquery-document-ready)

Comment: I don't think so, the .load() I meant was this https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

> Both are different and has no common load is function or method of
>   jquery and onload is event !

onload Execute a JavaScript when a page is finished loading:

```
 <body onload="myFunction()">
```

load , Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

```
 $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

Comment: jquery `load()` is not always used in combination with AJAX! It could also be used to detect the complete load of a element.

Answer (score 0):

Both action is same but jquery .load() required jquery library while javascript .onload is an in buit function doesn't require any framework and also faster then jquery load()

Comment: Do you have a reference to be sure that they are both the same?